# Using Terraform's helm_release, how do I set array or list values?

Tags: terraform, kubernetes-helm, terraform-provider-azure

For example, per the [helm chart documentation for Drupal](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/bitnami/drupal), the default value for `accessModes` is `["ReadWriteOnce"]` which translates to the following in the YAML:

```
...
accessModes
- ReadWriteOnce
```

When using the Terraform [helm_release](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/helm/latest/docs/resources/release) resource, the following do not work and the yaml file always shows the default from above:

```
  set {
    name  = "persistence.accessModes"
    value = "ReadWriteMany"
  }
```

```
  set {
    name  = "persistence.accessModes"
    value = "[\"ReadWriteMany\"]"
  }
```

```
  set {
    name  = "persistence.accessModes"
    value = "- ReadWriteMany"
  }
```

Comment: You have a typo `persistence.accesModes` --> `persistence.accessModes`. Make that change and see if it improves the situation.

Comment: Don't change your question after you got an answer to your original question. Accept the answer, if it was helpful, and ask a new question.

Comment: The second part you added is unrelated to the original question. The second part was throwing an error because you have `.` in the name that was unescaped. The answer you received from "The Fool" was correct.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You would set it the same way as with the helm CLI [--set](https://helm.sh/docs/intro/using_helm/#the-format-and-limitations-of---set) flag. For example, using the index notation.

> As of Helm 2.5.0, it is possible to access list items using an array index syntax. For example, --set servers[0].port=80

```
set {
  name  = "persistence.accessModes[0]"
  value = "ReadWriteMany"
}
```

The alternative syntax is using curly braces. Where you can add the list items separated with a comma between the braces.

> Lists can be expressed by enclosing values in { and }. For example, --set name={a, b, c}

```
set {
  name  = "persistence.accessModes"
  value = "{ReadWriteMany}"
}
```

Comment: Getting following error using {}: `Missing key/value separator: Expected an equals sign ("=") to mark the beginning of the attribute value.`

Comment: Thanks so much for posting, I was stuck on this for hours.

Answer (score 3):

## Updated terraform syntax

You can use [set_list](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/helm/latest/docs/resources/release#set_list)

For example:

```
set_list {
  name  = "persistence.accessModes"
  value = ["ReadWriteMany"]
}
```