# Set Helm Chart Values that are an Array

Tags: kubernetes-helm, terraform-helm-provider

Below is the information from my `values.yaml` file for our helm chart.

```
  apps:
  - name: acc1
    uri: "https://google.com"
    labels:
      env: acc1
      name: test1
  - name: acc2
    uri: "https://google.com"
    labels:
      env: acc2
      name: test2
```

I would like to use this in dynamic `set` block of Terraform , with `helm_release` resource. It would be great , if I get some advise on the same

Comment: Do you know how many items can exist in the list? Also, from where do you want to fetch this list in Terraform?

Comment: Yes, I would like to fetch all the items in this list

Comment: [Using Terraform's helm_release, how do I set array or list values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71754003/using-terraforms-helm-release-how-do-i-set-array-or-list-values) and the [`helm_release` documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/helm/latest/docs/resources/release) suggest the same syntax as `helm install --set`, but that's awkward for this complex structure.  Can you put the YAML in a Terraform `values = "..."` setting, perhaps?